# How to make Haskell GLUT using freeglut on Windows?

Tags: windows, opengl, haskell, glut, freeglut

How to make the Haskell GLUT binding using freeglut instead of the original GLUT on windows?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried building Haskell GLUT with freeglut installed?

Comment: I followed http://netsuperbrain.com/blog/posts/freeglut-windows-hopengl-hglut/, but configure GLUT with freeglut says it depends on OpenGL, StateVar, Tensor, But they are already installed. How to do that exactly?

Comment: I find a easy way doing this. Just clean out all the original GLUT lib stuff and download a precompiled freeglut.dll and change it to glut32.dll and save to C:\WINDOWS\system32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I find a easy way doing this. Just clean out all the original GLUT lib stuff and download a precompiled freeglut.dll and change it to glut32.dll and save to C:\WINDOWS\system32.
>
> Eric Wong

Comment: Should. Doesn't. For 64-bit Windows, 32-bit programs will only see what's actually `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`. But even if place `freeglut.dll` there, renamed to `glut32.dll`, it will not work. (`Main: user error (unknown GLUT call glutSetOption, check for freeglut`)